# bash script for apending dates onto files

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script which takes in a file as $1 and then copies it and appends the year,month, and date onto the end of the file. So for example if i had a file foo.txt it would turn into foo.txt.2010.11.16. I'm not really 100% sure how to do this, any suggestions?

Comment: "onto the end of the file" - Apparently you mean onto the end of the file *name*.

Answer (score 3):

Simple version:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp "$1" "$1".`date +%Y.%m.%d`
```

Fancier version:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#  date_tag_files file1 [file2 file3 ...]
#
for f in $*
do
    cp "$f" "$f".`date +%Y.%m.%d`
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `$(date ...)` to get the current date into an environment variable.

The following script allows you to pass in any number of file names and it will attempt to copy all of them to similar files with the date appended.

It gets the date *once* in case you try to run it around midnight and you want them all to get the same date even if you cross into the following day during the process.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]] ; then
    echo 'Usage: datecp <filename> ...'
    exit 1
fi

dt=$(date +%Y.%m.%d)
while [[ $# -ne 0 ]] ; do
    if [[ ! -f "$1" ]] ; then
        echo 'Warning:' $1 'is not a regular file, not copied'
    else
        newf="$1.$dt"
        cp "$1" "$newf"
        echo "$1" '-->' "$newf"
    fi

    shift
done
```

The output for the last one is along the lines of:

```
pax> datecp
Usage: datecp <filename> ...

pax> datecp xyz
xyz --> xyz.2010.11.17

pax> datecp xyz abc
xyz --> xyz.2010.11.17
abc --> abc.2010.11.17

pax> ./qq.sh xyz qwert abc
xyz --> xyz.2010.11.17
Warning: qwert is not a regular file, not copied
abc --> abc.2010.11.17
```